# Chrome Developer Tools Live Edit Button removed?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

[This page](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/13/debugging-javascript-with-chrome.aspx) mentions a "Live Edit Button" in the Chrome Developer Tools. It looks like a pencil with an ellipsis character. I think I've seen it before a few times, but can't find it anymore.
Is it disabled/hidden for certain scripts, perhaps? Or was it removed from the stable version of Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last versions of chrome Live edit mode became the only mode. That's why the button was removed.

Comment: Mode? What was the difference between the modes then?

Comment: The editor used to be read-only by default, and you had to click the Live Edit button to make changes to your code (editors are writable by default, whenever it makes sense). Now you can edit the editor contents without any preliminary actions. In order to apply the changes, you need to hit Ctrl-S.